# $Ham(M, \omega)$ acts transitively on $(M,\omega)$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a  compact and connected smooth manifold with a symplectic form $\omega$.

$Ham(M, \omega)$ denotes the space of hamiltonian symplectomorphisms of $(M,\omega)$.

I have the following statement in my lecture notes:

> Using Darboux’s theorem one can show that the action of $Ham(M, \omega)$ on M is transitive, that is: for any pair of points $p, q \in M$, there exists $\Phi \in Ham(M, \omega)$ such that $\Phi(p) = q$. The idea  is that Darboux's theorem to go from local to global, i.e. to show that points that are close to each other in the symplectic manifold can be mapped to each other via a Hamiltonian diffeomorphism.

**...which I unsuccesfully tried to prove. How is it done?**

I know that a symplectomorphism of $(M, \omega)$ is a diffeomorphism $\Phi : M \to M$ such that $\Phi ^∗\omega = \omega$. $\Phi$  is Hamiltonian if there exists a Hamiltonian isotopy $\phi_t$ such that $\Phi=\phi_1$.

And that $ Ham(M, \omega)$ is a normal subgroup of $Symp(M, \omega)$ (the space of symplectomorphisms ), if that is useful.

I am not sure what "points close to each other" means here and how to use to arrive to the thesis

Following the suggestion:

Let p, q be in M then By Darboux theorem there are open charts
$(U_p,\phi)$ and $(Uq,\psi)$ with $\phi$ and $\psi$ symplectomorphisms from $\Bbb R^{2n}$

But what do I do with this?

Comment: On $(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\omega_{std})$ can you find a hamiltonian symplectomorphism taking $0$ to an arbitrary point $p$?

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Sorry I am very new to all this, how would I do that?

Comment: Since $\omega_{std}$ has constant coefficients, any translation $x\mapsto x+p$ is a symplectomorphism. Can you write down a Hamiltonian which generates such a symplectomorphism?

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Not sure what "generates" mean and does Hamiltonian mean Hamiltonian vector field?

Comment: Generates as in, is the time 1 flow of. A Hamiltonian is a function which gives a vector field via the symplectic form. Before delving deeper into symplectic geometry, I would recommend reading more on the foundations. The book "symplectic topology" by McDuff and Salamon and the lecture notes of Da Silva are good resource!

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4885988/why-is-this-identity-of-hamiltonian-vector-fields-true-x-ftx-gt-circ, you have shown the linearity of the map that takes an Hamiltonian to its vector field. Try to apply Darboux's theorem, and see what are the Hamiltonian vector fields of the functions $q_1, p_1, q_2...$. Then use the linearity.

Comment: @ReiHenigman Could you give more details? I pasted my version of Darboux theorem I really don't know how Darboux or the linearity of the map that you mention are useful to solve this .  Are the vector fields of that coordinate functions simply $\dot q_1$, $\dot p_1$, etc ...? What do I do with those?

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Could you please elaborate? What would this HAmiltonian be?

Answer (score 4):

Translations of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ are generated by constant vector fields, i.e. the flow $x\mapsto x+ty$ is generated by the vector field $x\mapsto y$ (under the natural identification $T(\mathbb{R}^{2n})\cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}\times \mathbb{R}^{2n}$). For a constant vector field $X=\sum_{i,j}^nX^i \partial_{q^i}+Y_j\partial_{p_j}$  we have $\iota_{X}\omega=\sum X^idp_i-\sum Y_j dq^j$ and hence $d\iota_{X}\omega_{std}=0$. By the closedness of $\omega_{std}$, $\mathcal{L}_{X}\omega_{std}=0$ and hence the flow $x\mapsto x+ty$ is a symplectomorphism.

There are several ways to see that this flow is Hamiltonian. First off, we can write a Hamiltonian $H_y(p,q)=\sum X^ip_i-Y_jq^j=\omega(X,(p,q))$. But also, the Poincare lemma tells us that $\iota_X\omega$ is exact, i.e. $\iota_X\omega_{std}=dH$ for some function $H$ and hence there exists a Hamiltonian for this flow.

This tells us that $Ham(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\omega_{std})$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ since the time one flow of $x\mapsto x+ty$ sends $0$ to $p$.

Now, to show that $Ham(M,\omega)$ acts transitively, we need to show that given to points $p$ and $q$ there exists a Hamiltonian symplectomorphism taking $p$ to $q$. We must assume that $M$ is connected, since $Ham(M,\omega)\subset Diff_0(M)$  cannot switch connected components and hence the proposition is not true when $M$ is not connected.

Take a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ connecting $p$ to $q$ and cover $\gamma([0,1])$ by some number of Darboux charts $\psi_{\alpha}:U_{\alpha}\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$. We can take a finite number of these charts since $[0,1]$ is compact. Take $t_1,\cdots t_k\in [0,1]$ be a sequence of times such that $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$ are contained in a common Darboux chart $U_{\alpha_i}$ for $t_0=0$ and $t_{k+1}=1$ (this is guaranteed by taking sufficiently many). Define $$\kappa_i:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}, t\mapsto (1-t)\psi_{\alpha_i}(\gamma(t_i))+t\psi_{\alpha_i}(\gamma(t_{i+1})).$$ This $\kappa_{i}$ is just the straight line connecting $\psi_{\alpha_i}(\gamma(t_i))$ to $\psi_{\alpha_i}(\gamma(t_{i+1}))$. Now, let $\phi_i: M\to \mathbb{R}^{\geq0}$ be a smooth function which is identically $1$ in a neighborhood of $\psi_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(\kappa_i([0,1]))$ and is identically $0$ outside of $U_{\alpha}$. Define $v_i:=(\psi_{\alpha_i}(\gamma(t_i))-\psi_{\alpha_i}(\gamma(t_{i+1}))$. We can then write down the hamiltonian $H_i=\phi_i\cdot \psi_{\alpha}^*H_{v_i}$ as in my second paragraph. This Hamiltonian makes sense by use of the bump function.

The time one flow of $H_i$ takes $\gamma(t_i)$ to $\gamma(t_{i+1})$ as follows. Since $\phi_i$ is identically $1$ near $\psi_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(\kappa_i([0,1]))$, $\psi_{\alpha_{i}*}X_{H_i}=X_{v_i}$ in a neighborhood of $\kappa_i([0,1])$. The $\kappa_i$ is an integral curve of $X_{H_{v_i}}$ contained in the aforementioned neighborhood and hence $\psi_{\alpha_i}^{-1}\circ \kappa_i$ is an integral curve for $X_{H_i}$. The curve has $\psi_{\alpha_i}^{-1}\circ \kappa_i(0)=\gamma(t_i)$ and $\psi_{\alpha_i}^{-1}\circ \kappa_i(1)=\gamma(t_{i+1})$.

We can then conclude that $\Phi^i_1(\gamma(t_{i}))=\gamma(t_{i+1})$ for $\Phi^i_t$ the flow of the hamiltonian vector field $X_{H_i}$ and hence $(\Phi^k_1\circ \Phi^{k-1}_1\circ \cdots \circ \Phi^1_1)(p)=q$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About the first paragraph 1)Is the $\omega$ in the first paragraph the standard symplectic form? Shoudn't it be denoted something like $ \omega_0$ or$ \omega_{\text{std}}$ so that it doesn't it get mixed with the generic $\omega$ of my manifold M?  I am using $ \omega_{\text{std}}=\sum dq^i\wedge dp_i$ to check the computations in the first paragraph.

Comment: 2)Is the point $p$ in the map $x \mapsto x+p$ in $\Bbb R^{2n}$ or in$ \Bbb R^{4n}$ ? First you say it is a translation $\Bbb R^{2n}$, so I deduce $ p \in \Bbb  R^{2n}$ but then you say that   $x \mapsto p$ is a vector field using the natural identification, then it seems like $ p  \in \Bbb R^{4n}$ and then I guess $p = (x, v)$, with $v$ a tangent vector at $x \in \Bbb R^{2n}$ Moreover the notation $p$ surely has nothing to do with a vector of $2n$ components $p=(p_1,...p_n)$ where the $p_i$'s are half of the coordinates of $\Bbb R^{2n}$ (the other half being the $q_i$'s)  used in $X$, does it?

Comment: 3) Why do we have two vector fields to begin with or are they the same? The constant vector field $x \mapsto p$ that generates the flow, and the vector field X ?

Comment: "This tells us that $Ham(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\omega_{std})$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ since the time one flow of $x\mapsto x+ty$ sends $0$ to $p$. " But insn't  $x\mapsto x+ty$ itself the flow? And since this prove the transitivity in the case of (R^2n, w_Std)How does this prove that  a  generic point p is send to q?, because it only shows that 0 is sent to y. and p is sent to p+y.

Comment: So does it suffice to take y = q-p ?

Comment: Taking $y=q-p$ suffices. The more general point is that if I have a transformation $g$ which takes $0$ to $q$ and h which takes $0$ to $p$ then the transformation $hg^{-1}$ takes $p$ to $q$.

Comment: The point about the constant vector fields is that since $T(\mathbb{R}^{2n})\cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}\times \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ the specification of a vector field is equivalent to specifying a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ which in this case is the constant function $f(x)=y$ for all $x$.

Comment: 1) $\phi_i$ is the bump function, right? i don't understand why we need to bother considering it. Why wouldn't theHamiltonian $H_i $ make sense without it?

Comment: 2) Is there a typo in the next-to-last paragraph? "$\psi_{\alpha_{i}*}X_{H_i}=X_{v_i}$" Shouldn't it be  "$\psi_{{\alpha_{i}}}^*X_{H_i}=X_{v_i}$" ? And also two lines before that "$H_i=\phi_i\cdot \psi_{\alpha_i}^*H_{v_i}$" instead of "$H_i=\phi_i\cdot \psi_{\alpha}^*H_{v_i}$" This last one is a pullback of a function, rather that a vetor field, how does that work?

Comment: 3) The definition of hamiltonian symplectomorphism that I have is that $F$ is a hamiltonian symplect if it is a symplectomorphism and there exists a hamiltonian isotopy $\rho_t$ such that $\rho_1=F$. But I don't see you are proving it like that in the second paragraph. You proved that the translation let me call it $\phi_t:x \mapsto x+ty$ is a symplectomorphism but to prove the second condition where is the hamiltonian isotopy $\rho_t$ such that $\rho_1=\phi_t$?

Comment: As an alternative, note that the first part shows that the orbit of any point is open; this implies that every orbit is a connected component (any point in the closure of an orbit O has orbit that intersects O, hence must actually be O).