# Why is this identity of hamiltonian vector fields true: $ X_{F^t}+X_{{G^t}\circ (\varphi^t_F)^{-1}}=X_{F^t +G^t\circ (\varphi^t_F)^{-1}}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry

In the following proof, (source https://jmp.sh/X5KwZ1Zt)
[image]
[image]
Using statement (i) as stated I only get

$X_{F^t}+D\varphi_F^tX_{G^t}\circ (\varphi^t_F)^{-1}=X_{F^t}+X_{{G^t}\circ (\varphi^t_F)^{-1}}$  but why is this equal to $ X_{F^t +G^t\circ (\varphi^t_F)^{-1}}$ ?

Edit:

Trying to prove that the map $M:F\mapsto X_F$ is linear:

$M(F)=X_F, M(G)=X_G, M(\alpha F+\beta G)=X_{\alpha F+\beta G}$

By definition of Hamiltonian vector field

$i_{X_F}\omega=dF$, $i_{X_G}\omega=dG$

and

$i_{X_{\alpha F +\beta G}}\omega=d(\alpha F +\beta G)=\alpha dF +\beta dG =\alpha i_{X_F}\omega +\beta i_{X_G}\omega$

But I don't know how to link this to $\alpha M(F) +\beta M (G)$

Comment: The map from $F$ to $X_F$ is a linear map, so $X_F + X_G=X_{F+G}$. This can be checked by the definition of Hamiltonian vector field $i_{X_F}\omega = dF$.

Comment: @Threeaggies Look at my edit, I tried proving that but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: The last line just continues as $=i_{\alpha X_F}\omega + i_{\beta X_G}\omega =i_{\alpha X_F + \beta X_G}\omega$.

Comment: Follow @Threeaggies comments, and use the non-degenaracy of $\omega$ for the last step.