# Is a hamiltonian isotopy real-valued of manifold-valued?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

I have looked everywhere and I can't find  a clear definition of hamiltonian isotopy. I have these definitions in my lecture notes but they are rather confusing
[image]

Acording to the last definition a Hamiltonian isotopy $\phi_t$  (the one they given in the definition of Hamiltonian symplectomorphism)  is a map $M \to M$, otherwise the equality $\Phi=\phi_1$ would not make sense right? Since a symplectomorphism is a diﬀeomorphism $\Phi : M → M$ . Moreover since the isotopy  $\phi_t: M \to M $ is a flow , it is by definition the identity on M at t=0 so more reason for it to be a map $M → M$

On the other hand it says that a  Hamiltonian isotopy is the isotopy generated by a Hamiltonian vector field $X_t$ so $\phi_t$ plays the role of $H_t$ in the definition above in the next-to-last paragraph and it is a map $M \to \Bbb R$

I ran into trouble when I was trying to prove that Ham(M, ω) is a subgroup of Symp(M, ω)
I started by taking $\Phi,\Psi\in Ham(M,\omega)$ so by definition there exist Hamiltonian isotopies $\phi_t$ and $\psi_t$ s.t $\phi_1=\Phi$ and $\psi_t=\Psi$ and to start with I wanted to argue that the composition $\phi_t\circ\psi_t$ is smooth, but composing them makes no sense if they are maps $M \to \Bbb R$. So I thought the definition must be wrong but I have checked in several places and in some places they do start proofs by taking Hamiltonian isotopies as real-valued , while in others as $M \to  M$. But if both definitions are correct how do I make sense of the composition?

**Can someone clarify these points? What are the correct definitions and how to I fix the start of the proof (make sense of composition)?**

Edit------------unrelated to this question:

[image]

Comment: The isotopy is generated by the vector field means that the isotopy behaves like the flow of that vector field, so for each time t, it is a diffeomorphism of the manifold. Does this help?

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon Sorry, not really .I don't see how that answers my questions. What is the correct codomain of a Hamiltonian isotopy? Or the definition of isotopy in connection to the Ham vector field has a different definition that that in Ham symplect.? I should be able to make sense of composition or Ham$(M \omega$) wouldn't be a group

Comment: Your definition of an isotopy is incorrect. An isotopy is not a map $M\to M$, but a map $M\times [0,1]\to M$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I meant when t is fixed. Otherwise I couldn't make sense of composition $\phi\circ \psi$, but If I get rid of t by fixing it, I can make sense of $\rho_t:=\phi_t \circ \psi_t$. And then put back the t to get $\rho:[0,1]\times M$ Although I can't say $\rho=\phi \circ \psi$

Comment: You still should not misuse the terminology. In any case, having the codomain $\mathbb R$ for an isotopy is utterly wrong. I am still unsure what your actual question is. Are you asking about codomains? Or for a proof that the set if Hamiltonian symplectomorphims forms a group?

Comment: @MoisheKohan  I was trying to clarify the definition of hamiltonian isotopy It looks like the the hamiltonian isotopy of the last paragraph is not the same hamiltonian isotopy of the next-to-last paragraph.  I guess I realized that there are two isotopies in play. The one that plays the role of flow $\phi:[0,1]\times M \to M$ and it looks like the smooth function $H: [0,1]\times M \to \Bbb R$ that generates a hamiltonian ie $-d H_t =id_{X_H} \omega$ is also a different isotopy.

Comment: My suggestion is to read the definition of an isotopy and how it differs from the definition of a homotopy. You can find both on Wikipedia. This will help you to formulate a proper question if you still have one.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ok, on another hand, could you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4884835/hamm-omega-acts-transitively-on-m-omega?noredirect=1#comment10423771_4884835. I could really use some help there

Comment: What book are you reading? Transitivity is a very soft result proven, for instance, in Banyaga's book.

Comment: By the way, where did you find "they do start proofs by taking Hamiltonian isometries as real-valued"? To begin with, no decent text will refer to a Hamiltonian map as an "isometry." You are likely misreading your sources or they are written in physicists and should be avoided when you are learning the subject. Also, math texts will distinguish between Hamiltonian functions (which are real-valued) and Hamiltonian maps (manifold-valued).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am reading lecture notes and consulting Salamon. Sorry I meant isotopies (instead of isometry). I fixed that. I believed that the function $H(t,x):[0,1]\times M \to M$ that is used to defined a Hamiltonian vector was an isometry

Comment: @MoisheKohan Banyaga's book, which title? There isn't any with the word symplectic on it

Comment: "The structure of classical diffeomorphism groups."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion stems from abuse of terminology. There are several different things in symplectic geometry which all have the adjective "Hamiltonian":

1. *Time-dependent Hamiltonian functions* on a manifold $M$, which are smooth functions
   $$
   H: M\times [0,1]\to {\mathbb R}. 
   $$
   Such $H$ can be regarded as a *homotopy* between the functions $H(\cdot, 0)$ and $H(\cdot, 1)$.
2. *Time-dependent Hamiltonian vector fields*, denoted $X_t$, which are maps
   $$
   M\times [0,1]\to TM, (p,t)\mapsto X_t(p)\in T_pM 
   $$
   (satisfying further properties).
3. *Time-dependent Hamiltonian maps* (which is suboptimal) or *Hamiltonian isotopies* (which is better), which are maps
   $$
   G: M\times [0,1]\to M
   $$
   (satisfying further properties). Such a map is an *isotopy* between the identity map $G(\cdot, 0)$ and the diffeomorphism $G(\cdot, 1)$ (the *time 1 map* of the isotopy $G$).
4. *Hamiltonian maps* or *Hamiltonian symplectomorphisms*, which are maps
   $$
   \Phi: M\to M
   $$
   for which there exists a Hamiltonian isotopy $G$ such that $\Phi=G(\cdot, 1)$ (i.e. $\Phi$ is the time 1 map of a Hamiltonian isotopy).

While you are still learning basics of the subject, it is best to avoid conflating these notions and make sure you use different words for different concepts. For instance, maps in (4) should **never** be referred to as **isotopies** and functions in (1) should **never** be referred to as **Hamiltonian maps**. In physics literature one routinely calls functions in (1) "Hamiltonians." I suggest, you avoid doing so at this stage.

Comment: I checked the book that you quoted I guess tou refer to Lemma 2.1.10: The transitivity lemma. The group $Diff^r(M)_0$ is strongly p-fold transitive for all p provided that the  dimension of M is at least two. Is transitivity the same as strong 1-fold transitivity ? Although I don't know why we need the "strong" adjective. The proof does not seem to use Darboux lemma as expected though, or maybe I just don't notice where they use it. See screenshot above

Comment: @darkside Yes, strongly 1-fold transitive is the same as transitive. He implicitly uses Darboux when he says "chart $\phi$": he uses the fact that in this chart the symplectic structure is standard.